# Unaddressed CSS conflict, webkit-transform causing overlap

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, web-component, webkit-transform

I am using a [Canvas](https://themeforest.net/item/canvas-the-multipurpose-html5-template/9228123) template to make a website. I am trying to combine elements from the [Flip Cards](http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/flip-cards.html) with other elements. Specifically modal boxes and light boxes, but the flip card text keeps on acting up, here are a few screenshots:

[modal bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OahRd.jpg)

[nav bar bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Ig0.jpg)

As you can see the flip card text is interfering not only with the modal boxes but the navbar as well.

I think I narrowed it down to this class:

```css
.flip-card-inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-perspective: inherit;
  perspective: inherit;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

When I remove

```css
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
```

the overlap is gone, but then the flip card is broken.

How can I fix this?